# Programatically search gridjs table (with javascript)

Tags: gridjs

Using [gridjs.io](https://gridjs.io/), I would like to perform a search when the gridjs table is initialized. More generally speaking, I would like to know how to programatically use the search without the user using the input field.

What I tried:

- enabled search plugin (search works perfectly fine when using the input field)
- i tried "minicking" user input by selecting the input field with javascript and changing its
  value to my keyword. This did not filter the table. Only when manually typing the
  filtering is applied.

**Example Code not working**:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
const grid = new Grid({
  columns: ['Name', 'Email', 'Phone Number'],
  search: true,
  data: [
    ['John', 'john@example.com', '(353) 01 222 3333'],
    ['Mark', 'mark@gmail.com',   '(01) 22 888 4444'],
    ['Eoin', 'eo3n@yahoo.com',   '(05) 10 878 5554'],
    ['Nisen', 'nis900@gmail.com',   '313 333 1923']
  ]
});
grid.render(document.getElementById("wrapper"));

// SEARCH/FILTER WITH JAVASCRIPT (NOT WORKING):
document.querySelector("input.gridjs-input").value = "John";
```

**Result**
The grid should be filtered, but it still shows all rows. The filter event was not dispatched. How can I dispatch the event with javascript?

[image]

Comment: I found out that I need to dispatch the search event specified in the typescript source code here: https://github.com/grid-js/gridjs/blob/ddcc143bc4e4994acdbfba3caf0f7897b3ed077d/packages/gridjs/src/view/plugin/search/actions.ts#L9, but dont know how to import and acces this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input element has an input Event listener attached to it [(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3k7H.jpg)

You can create and dispatch the event using this code:

```js
// Find the gridjs searchbox and set the value
var el = document.querySelector('.gridjs-search-input');
el.value = newVal;

// Create and dispatch the event
var event = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});
el.dispatchEvent(event);
```